# Flask Setup on IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: azure, iis, flask, server, fastcgi

I am trying to host a Flask Web app on a Windows Server 2012.
I have followed the instructions in http://developer.e-power.com.kh/publish-flask-on-iis/
At first it did not work but after enabling the HTTP Activation Windows Feature I was able to get the following error message after browsing http://localhost:80/ :

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\convnet\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) 
File "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\convnet\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name) 
File "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\convnet\wfastcgi.py", line 551, in get_wsgi_handler raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name) 
ValueError: "app.app" could not be imported 
StdOut: 
StdErr:
```

The web.config file, which was automatically generated after following the instructions in the link above, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="FlaskHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python27\python.exe|c:\inetpub\wwwroot\convnet\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have app object is importable from app.py. Looks like it doesn't find it:

```
ValueError: "app.app" could not be imported
```

Comment: Could you eloborate a bit more on this?